# How to upload file to dropbox from url?

Tags: android, upload, external, dropbox

I can find lots of tutorials and examples on how to upload a file from sdcard to dropbox account. But how can I upload a file that is not in sdcard and all I have is url? I don't want to download it and then upload it, because file is like 400MB size.

Comment: I use the URL Droplet ( https://www.urldroplet.com ) and I don't know another way to do it. But yeah, I'm not using it programmatically.

Comment: I need something like that, but in android.

Comment: Would [the Chooser](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/chooser/android) be an option for you? (Is this action initiated by a user?)

Comment: @smarx I don't need to access dropbox files, I need to upload file from url to dropbox

Answer (score 4):

[Save Web Files](http://ctrlq.org/save/) *(http://ctrlq.org/save/)* can do it. (just visit the website on your android)

Comment: I needed API for this similar thing

Comment: How does that website work? I want to implement something similar on my own dedicated computer. Does it just download it then upload it to dropbox?

Comment: @bs7280 I'm not sure. If you click on the "Learn More" link it says "The download is from cloud to cloud." And if you follow the first link on that page to the author's website, it says "the file saving app is powered by [Ink File Picker](http://www.filepicker.io)". You could also email the author of Save Web Files using the "Need Help?" link. There's also similar sites & apps that you can research to possibly find other ways of doing it, like [UploadCloud.net](http://uploadcloud.net), [PushBullet](https://www.pushbullet.com), [IFTTT](http://ifttt.com), & [Tasker](http://tasker.dinglisch.net).

Answer (score 2):

Dropbox has implemented this as a native API call: https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2015/06/programmatically-saving-a-url-to-dropbox/

This is currently being re-implemented by DBinbox.com to be more user-friendly :)